# if role is admin append a td

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

i need to check if user role is admin, append a `<td>`to the table. in other word i have a table as below in my jsp page:

```
title  |   description  |   action
-----------------------------------
....          ......         answer
```

i want when user role is admin, in the action column see is added. like this:

```
   title  |   description  |   action
    -----------------------------------
    ....          ......       answer|see
```

my jquery code for this is:

```
$('#my-rows').append($('<tr>')
            .append($('<td>').text(poll.title))
            .append($('<td>').text(poll.description))
            .append($('<td>').append($('<a style="text-decoration: none">').attr({
                'onclick' : 'VoteFor(' +poll.poll_id+ ')'}).text('answer'))).append(('${hasRoleAdmin}' == true ? $('<a>').attr({
            'onclick' : 'ViewPoll(' +poll.poll_id+ ')'}).text('see'):'')))
```

and `hasRoleAdmin` is a variable that i have defined in my jsp page like this:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" var="hasRoleAdmin"></sec:authorize>
```

but it doesn't work and my table is as what i showed first earlier above and i can't get `see` as it is in second table. how can i put my condition on append? can you help?

Comment: Are you sure that `'${hasRoleAdmin}'` prints out `'true'` ?

Comment: unfortunately the debugger doesn't work fine in javascript. it should, because i log in as an admin. why it shouldn't? you mean beside this the rest of code is ok?

Comment: What was asked was did you look at the generated source to see what gets output to browser where you have `${hasRoleAdmin}`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly -

Since you have Spring security in picture, you can simply:

Hard code your  wherever you want.

wrap it in your spring security tags something like this:

```
 <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')"><td>your</td></sec:authorize>
```

Handle security in your SecurityConfig.

should do the trick. That means, no other role should be able to view that tag at all other than Admin. Let the spring security handle it for you. There is no need to hide/unhide/enable/disable using JS/JQ etc.

Comment: but how can i put <sec:authorize> tab in javascript?because in jsp i just have three headers. and the fields are filled by javascript. can u explain a bit more?

Comment: append spring security tags around your <td> as I mentioned : <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')"><yourtd></sec:authorize>

Comment: i did     append($('<sec:authorize access="hasRole(\'ROLE_ADMIN\')">').append($('<a style="text-decoration: none">').attr({'onclick': 'ViewPoll(' + poll.poll_id + ')'}).text('see'))))                                                                                  but it doesn't work and the link is visible for all roles